# Tangent space to the tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces

I want to know why it holds that, for some smooth manifold $M$,

$T_pM \cong T_x(T_pM)$

where $x \in T_pM$.

My main questions:

-How does the isomorphism look?
-As far as I know, the tangent space is defined for manifolds, is $T_pM$ a manifold itself?

Comment: $T_pM$ is a manifold of the same dimension as $M$

Comment: This is true just because both vector spaces have dimension $\dim M$. But more is true: For any real or complex vector space $\Bbb V$ and any $v \in \Bbb V$ there is a *canonical* isomorphism $T_v \Bbb V \cong \Bbb V$.

Comment: Hm I still don't understand what $T_vV$ means since $V$ is not necessarily a manifold (or is it?)

Comment: Every finite dimensional vector space can be given a smooth manifold structure.

Comment: Is it correct, that then this manifold has a global chart $\varphi=(y_1,...,y_n)$ and therefore we can define an isomorphism between $T_vV $ and $V$ in the way that $T_vV \ni x =\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_i} |_v \mapsto (x_1,...,x_n)$?